# How to navigate to uri on HttpClient Post - RedirectPayment?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclient

I am trying implement redirect payment using httpclient i am making request

```
Uri BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, BaseAddress);
request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues)
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

and the response i getting has got {StatusCode:200, ReasonPhrase:'OK'.... }

I am using HtmlClient instead of html form post. I need to post to one BaseAddress with some data. This data has got an idpass and some extra datas. Using this idpass i will get access to BaseAddress.

How to redirect to this page BaseAddress after post succeed? I thought by posting to BaseAddress the datas it should redirect me to it instanly if succeded the post. I tried this

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
  return Redirect(response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

it is redirect me to the BaseAddress but with idpass null.
so how make it work while i make request it will auto redirect me to BaseAddress with idpass and other datas that i pass? Sorry for inconvience i do not know how ask this question properly?

In client this done by doing this, but i need do this in serverside.

```
<form id="shopform" name="test" method="POST"
action=BaseAddress accept-charset="UTF-8" >
<input type="hidden" name="idpass" value="1011010"/>
<input type="hidden" name="lang" value="en”/>
........
</form>
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Sorry, the question was edited.